# My suggestions div stay behind of another div

Tags: html, css

I have an input and an element for suggestions when a user starts typing. But when I type input text suggestions are stay back of next section. I want all suggestions can show.

```css
div.suggestions {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

div.suggestions a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

div.suggestions a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-lg-6">
  <input id="search" type="text" class="input-text input-large full-width" placeholder="wpisz region, miejscowość lub hotel">
  <div id="suggestion" class="suggestions"></div>
  <p class="hidden" id="values"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly share full code in snippet.

Comment: still needs some more explanation.

Comment: @ths  suggestion div should be most top position from other divs

Comment: @CodyCoderson impossible big project for snippet

Comment: could you make a demo that has nearly the same functionality in which you encountered the discussed issue.

Comment: What is happening to your suggestion div?, Is it hiding behind some other div?

Comment: @ImmortalDude Yes like you said.